# Running "jsonlint test.json" from cmd (Command Prompt), returns ENOENT: no such file or directory, errno: -4058

Tags: json, jsonlint

I'm running this command "jsonlint test.json" from cmd (Command Prompt). 
 It returns ENOENT: no such file or directory, errno: -4058.  If I enter the text directly into https://jsonlint.com, it says valid.  I don't think its not valid, just says it can't find it.

I'm running the cmd prompt as administrator, going to the C:\Temp directory, then typing in from C:\Temp>jsonlint test.json

The test.json file exists in the C:\Temp folder.  Any thoughts on why it says it can't find it?

I'm afraid I'm totally new to jsonlint, so I don't know if I'm not typing something correctly, or what.  Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. nevermind.  I'm embarrassed now.  I solved it once I figured out the machine I'm working on wasn't displaying the file extensions, so my "test.json" was really called, "test.json.txt"  Stupid Windows!